# How to conditionally map two identical variables in nginx?

Tags: nginx

I would like to set the variable `$sub` conditionally dependent on `$request_uri` and `$host`.

```
map $request_uri $sub {
    default       front;
    ~^/api/.*     api;
    ~^/rest/.*    rest;
}

map $host $sub {
    hostnames;

    #default    $sub; # Tried, no success

    ping.*     ping;
    admin.*    admin;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name _;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_param HTTP_X_SUB $sub;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;;
    }
}
```

I thought nginx will not overwrite `$sub` in `map $host $sub` if the hostname is not in the list, but unfortunatly it just blanks out `$sub`.

So basically it should be like if `$host` is "ping" or "admin" set `$sub` accordingly. If hostname did not match, check for `$request_uri`.

Any idea how to archive that statement?

**EDIT:** Extended the config.

Comment: You seem to be checking two different contexts. You probably need two different variables. What do you actually intend to do with this variable?

Comment: The second `map` needs a new variable name, which is then used in the `add_header` statement. Otherwise, using a `map` variable as the `default` of another `map` works perfectly well.

Comment: @RichardSmith As you can see, I tried using `$sub` as default of the second map. No success. It' just empty then. `$sub` defines the internal working dir and it can not be devided into two variables.

Comment: The problem is that you have used the same variable for both maps. Use a different name and it will work.

Comment: @RichardSmith I want to avoid ifs in nginx. I thought nginx can take another variable as default, which is not the case obviously.

Comment: I don't know what you mean. Where is the `if`? 1st map generates `$sub1`, second map generates `$sub2` and uses `$sub1` as a default. HTTP_X_SUB is set to the value of `$sub2` (which may or may not be the same as `$sub1`). There is no `if`.